# How to create a seaborn heatmap by hour/day from timestamp with multiple data points per hour

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame with a `date` column which is a `timestamp`. There are multiple data points per hour of a day eg `2014-1-1 13:10, 2014-1-1 13:20` etc. I want to group the data points from the same hour of a specific day and then create a heatmap using seaborn and plot a different column.

I have tried to use `groupby` but I'm not sure how to specify i want the `hour` and `day`

```
date             data
2014-1-1 13:10  50
2014-1-1 13:20  51
2014-1-1 13:30  51
2014-1-1 13:40  56
2014-1-1 13:50  67
2014-1-1 14:00  43
2014-1-1 14:10  78
2014-1-1 14:20  45
2014-1-1 14:30  58
```

I want to combine the data by its mean value

Comment: How do you want to combine the data points within the hour? Also you should include some sample data in your question.

Comment: @QuangHoangSorry about that, I have edited the question with some sample data. I want to combine the data by the hours mean value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dt.strftime('%H')` to get the hours, and `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%D')` or `dt.normalize()` for the days

```
sns.heatmap(df.groupby([df.date.dt.normalize(), df.date.dt.strftime('%H:00')])
   ['data'].mean()
   .rename_axis(index=['day','hour'])
   .unstack(level=0)
)
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: for the weeks, we can use a similar approach

```
s = (df.groupby([df.date.dt.isocalendar().week,
                 df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
                 df.date.dt.strftime('%H:00')])
       ['data'].mean()
       .rename_axis(index=['week','day','hour'])
    )

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,10))
for w, ax in zip(s.index.unique('week'), axes.ravel()):
    sns.heatmap(s.loc[w].unstack(level='day'), ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Week {w}')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: For a larger data set (I'm plotting 4 weeks of data) is it possible to split up the heatmaps by week?

Comment: @TBolton what do you mean split by week?

Comment: I am plotting 4 weeks of data, instead of having one large heatmap I want to split it into 4 heatmaps, one for each week of data.